# Prevent credential prompt on rest calls

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, search, rest, authentication

I have a search results page and each result item is a card with information about the site i'm returning.

Within that card, I'm making a REST call using pnp to get the documents from the site:

[image]

The issue I'm having is that when a user is removed from a site, which happens a lot in our scenario, if he returns to the search page (which provides results by default) they are prompted for credentials for each site in the result because they no longer have access but the Search index hasn't updated yet.

Is there a way to suppress the credential prompt and simply fail silently